# PLSQL Dynamic content if else condition in html code in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

how can i use if else condition to hide the DIV in oracle apex plsql dynamic content.

here is below code

```
    declare
    l_html clob;
    V_LINE_ID NUMBER;
begin
    l_html := '<div class="main-container">';
    for i in (
        select LINE_ID,
       HEADER_ID,
       VENDOR_ID,(select vendor_name from po_vendors@apps where vendor_id = cspl.VENDOR_ID) vendor,
       ITEM_CATEGORY,  ITEM_TYPE, nvl(ITEM_CODE,'-') ITEM_CODE,  ITEM_SOURCE,  nvl(TEST_REPORT,'-') TEST_REPORT, nvl(COMPOSITION,'-') COMPOSITION,   
       nvl(MATERIAL,'-') MATERIAL,  nvl(WIDTH,'-') WIDTH,  nvl(COLOR,'-') COLOR,  INV_ITEM_ID,   
       nvl(INV_ITEM_NAME,'-') INV_ITEM_NAME, nvl(THICKNESS,'-') THICKNESS,   nvl(TEX,'-') TEX,    nvl(ITEM_COUNT,'-') ITEM_COUNT,   
       nvl(ELONGATION,'-') ELONGATION,       nvl(STRENGTH,'-') STRENGTH,    nvl(STRETCH_RECOVERY,'-') STRETCH_RECOVERY, 
       nvl(DIMENSIONAL_STABILITY,'-') DIMENSIONAL_STABILITY,            nvl(SLIDER,'-')  SLIDER, nvl(ELEMENTS,'-') ELEMENTS,
       nvl(TAPE,'-') TAPE,     nvl(ITEM_FINISH,'-') ITEM_FINISH,        nvl(FUNCTION_TYPE,'-') FUNCTION_TYPE,    
       nvl(SLIDER_FUNCTION,'-') SLIDER_FUNCTION, nvl(SHRINKAGE,'-') SHRINKAGE,   nvl(HL,'-') HL, nvl(FIBER_CONTENT,'-') FIBER_CONTENT, 
       nvl(CRAFTS,'-') CRAFTS, nvl(FLUTES_TYPE,'-') FLUTES_TYPE, nvl(FLUTE_HARDNER,'-') FLUTE_HARDNER, nvl(ECT,'-') ECT, 
       nvl(bst,'-') bst, nvl(fct,'-') fct, nvl(MARKING,'-') MARKING, nvl(ADHESIVE_STRENGTH,'-') ADHESIVE_STRENGTH, 
       nvl(TEMPERATURE,'-') TEMPERATURE,  nvl(PRESSURE,'-') PRESSURE, nvl(TIME_INFO,'-') TIME_INFO,  nvl(DESIGN_ARTWORK,'-') DESIGN_ARTWORK,
       nvl(QA_GLUE,'-') QA_GLUE, nvl(CRITERIA,'-') CRITERIA, nvl(DESCRIPTION,'-') DESCRIPTION,    nvl(REMARKS,'-') REMARKS,
       ENABLED,     CREATION_DATE,       CREATED_BY,       LAST_UPDATE_DATE,       LAST_UPDATE_BY,CSPL.WEAVE, CSPL.DYE_STUFF, CSPL.MOQ, CSPL.LEAD_TIME,
       'Attach' Attachments
  from apex_data_c1 cspl
 where HEADER_ID = :P14_HEADER_ID
    ) loop
        l_html := l_html || '    
            <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                <div  class="front">

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Vendor Name:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.vendor ||' </h6> 
                    </div>
                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Item Category:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.ITEM_CATEGORY ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Item Type:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.ITEM_TYPE ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Item Code:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.ITEM_CODE ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Vendor Source:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.ITEM_SOURCE ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Test Report:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.TEST_REPORT ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Composition:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.COMPOSITION ||' </h6> 
                    </div>

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Construction:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.MATERIAL ||' </h6> 
                    </div>

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Width:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.WIDTH ||' </h6> 
                    </div>

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Color:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.COLOR ||' </h6> 
                    </div>

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Inventory Item:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.INV_ITEM_NAME ||' </h6> 
                    </div>
                    
                     <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Weight:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.THICKNESS ||' </h6> 
                    </div>

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Tex:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.TEX ||' </h6> 
                    </div>

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Item Count:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.ITEM_COUNT ||' </h6> 
                    </div>

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Elongation:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.ELONGATION ||' </h6> 
                    </div>  

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Strength:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.STRENGTH ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Stretch Recovery:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.STRETCH_RECOVERY ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Dimensional Stability:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Dimensional_Stability ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Slider:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Slider ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Elements:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Elements ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Tape:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Tape ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Item Finish:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Item_Finish ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Function Type:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Function_Type ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Slider Function:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Slider_Function ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Shrinkage:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Shrinkage ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> HL:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.HL ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Fiber Content:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Fiber_Content ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Crafts:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Crafts ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Flutes Type:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Flutes_Type ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Flute Hardner:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Flute_Hardner ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> ECT:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.ECT ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> BST:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.BST ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> FCT:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.FCT ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Marking:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Marking ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Adhesive Strength:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Adhesive_Strength ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Temperature:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Temperature ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Pressure:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Pressure ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Time Info:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Time_Info ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 


                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Design Artwork:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Design_Artwork ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> QA Glue:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Qa_Glue ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Criteria:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Criteria ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Description:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Description ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 

                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> Remarks:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.Remarks ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 
                      

                      <!-- front DIV closed -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        '        ;
        
    end loop;
:P14_LINE_ID := V_LINE_ID;
    l_html := l_html || '</div>';

    apex_util.prn(l_html, false);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop statement you can determine what to print using an `IF / ELSE`  statement. For example if you want to skip vendor "Internal" then you'd do the following:

```
...
 where HEADER_ID = :P14_HEADER_ID
    ) loop
      -- start of if
      IF i.vendor != 'Internal' THEN 

        l_html := l_html || '    
            <div class="flip-container">
...
           </div>
        '        ;
      -- start of else
      ELSE. 
        -- don't show
        NULL;
      END IF;
        
    end loop;
...
```

Comment: hI I have checked as you guided but here i get an error when compile the plsql code

ORA-06550: line 254, column 22: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || member submultiset The symbol ";" was substituted for "IF" to continue.

Comment: 'IF i.FCT IS NULL THEN'
                        <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4>    </h4>
                    </div>
                    'ELSE'
                    <div  class="HEADING1">
                            <h4> FCT:  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="DATA1">
                            <h6> '||i.FCT ||' </h6> 
                    </div> 
                    'END IF'

Comment: The error indicates the error is before the "IF" keyword. Please add an update to your post with the lines of code around that "IF" statement. The statement in your comment has quotes around the "IF", "ELSE" and "END IF". There should be no quotes - plenty of [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS004) on this very basic pl/sql syntax.